# Strip out a substring beginning with a specific word and ending with "."

Tags: php, string, substring, strpos, display-cutouts

From the middle of a text I need to cut out a sentence or better the information about the ingredients of a product.
The logic behind is always the same.
Starting with "Ingredients" ending with a dot "."

For example (this is my `$prodDesc`):

```
Coca Cola is the most famous soft drink in America.
Ingredients: Carbon water, Sugar (sucrose or high-fructose corn syrup (HFCS) depending on country of origin), Caramel colour (E150d), Phosphoric Acid, Caffeine (34 mg/12 fl oz), natural Flavours. Nutrition Facts: 1 Serving Per Container - Serving Size: 1 Can. Total Fat 0g Sodium 45mg Total Carbohydrate 39g Total Sugars (Includes 39g Added Sugars) Cholesterol 0mg Protein 0g Vitamin D 0g Calcium 0g Iron 0g Potassium 0g
```

I tried so far with `strpros` but the fact it is in the middle of the text I get everything from "Ingredients" on until the end.

I need only this as output:

```
$prodIngredientsData = "Ingredients: Carbon water, Sugar (sucrose or high-fructose corn syrup (HFCS) depending on country of origin), Caramel colour (E150d), Phosphoric Acid, Caffeine (34 mg/12 fl oz), natural Flavours."
```

Given that $prodDesc is the description above, my try was:

```
$searchstring = $prodDesc;
$prodIngredientsData = false;
if (strpos($searchstring, "Ingredients") !== false)
{
    $sd_array = explode("Ingredients", $searchstring);
    $sd = end($sd_array);
    $prodIngredientsData = "Ingredients " . $sd;
}
else {
    $prodIngredientsData = false;
}
```

But as mentioned, I get everything on from "Ingredients" until the end of the description. But it should stop at the first full stop in the example at "Ingredients... ...natural Flavours."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with preg_match:

```
$prodIngredientsData = "Ingredients: Carbon water, Sugar (sucrose or high-fructose corn syrup (HFCS) depending on country of origin), Caramel colour (E150d), Phosphoric Acid, Caffeine (34 mg/12 fl oz), natural Flavours."
preg_match('/(Ingredients:([^.]+))/', $prodIngredientsData, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

> Ingredients: Carbon water, Sugar (sucrose or high-fructose corn syrup
>   (HFCS) depending on country of origin), Caramel colour (E150d),
>   Phosphoric Acid, Caffeine (34 mg/12 fl oz), natural Flavou rs

Comment: I guess this one is the more elegant version then using strpos twice. It works great, thank you. Anyhow I found that some data was not having a full stop after the ingredients list. So I combined preg_match with another strpos ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. *`$prodIngredientsData`* stores the string after **"Ingredients "**. So, we need to extract the string between **"Ingredients "** and the first **"."**

```
if (strpos($searchstring, "Ingredients") !== false)
{
    $sd_array = explode("Ingredients", $searchstring);
    $sd = end($sd_array);
    $prodIngredientsData = "Ingredients " . $sd;
    $end_pos   = strpos($prodIngredientsData, ".");
    $prodIngredientsData = substr($prodIngredientsData , 0, $end_pos+1);

} else {
    $prodIngredientsData = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was actually a good approach. I combined this one with the preg_match from Saeed M. and got covered the case if there is no fullstop at the end of the ingredients list! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You need regex. Something like
 `preg_match('/Ingredients.*?\./', $string, $match);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos` again to find the full stop, and shorten the string.

```php
$searchstring = $prodDesc;
$prodIngredientsData = false;
$ingredientsPos = strpos($searchstring, "Ingredients");
if ($ingredientsPos !== false) {
    $prodIngredientsData = substr($searchstring, $ingredientsPos);
    $stopPos = strpos($prodIngredientsData, ".");
    if ($stopPos !== false) {
        $prodIngredientsData = substr(
                    $prodIngredientsData,
                    0,
                    $stopPos + 1);
    }
}
echo $prodIngredientsData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this kind of tasks.

```
$strippedString = preg_replace('/Ingredients:[^\.]+\./', '', $prodIngredientsData);
```

The regex `Ingredients:[^\.]+\.` indicates a string (placed basically everywhere in the `$prodIngredientsData`) matching (literally) `Ingredients:` and followed by any set of chars but a point `[^\.]` with at least an occurrence (`+`) and ending with a point `\.`

Please pay attention: if ingredients has a point somewhere and continues, this basically will strip off only a certain part of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the begin and end with `str_pos` and save the string between them, then do next search till to end. Check the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dabcb256f4d67dbd4f0a3c2fb86338fc6bf9320d)

```
$begin_offset = 0;
$result = [];
$string = ""
while(false !== ($begin_offset=strpos($string,"Ingredients",$begin_offset)) && false !== ($end_offset=strpos($string,".",$begin_offset))){
    $result[] = substr($string,$begin_offset,$end_offset-$begin_offset);
    $begin_offset = $end_offset;
}
var_dump($result);
```

The demo result,

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(195) "Ingredients: Carbon water, Sugar (sucrose or high-fructose corn syrup (HFCS) depending on country of origin), Caramel colour (E150d), Phosphoric Acid, Caffeine (34 mg/12 fl oz), natural Flavours."
  [1]=>
  string(77) "Ingredients: Carbon water, Sugar (sucrose or high-fructose corn syrup (HFCS)."
}
```